# Can the Heat Equation be Averaged Over a Region?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus

I am doing a project for my partial differential equations class in which I am motivating the definition of a weak solution. To get started, I assumed that $T$ was a solution to $\nabla^2 T = \partial T/\partial t$, and then I considered the averaged version
$$\hat T_D(x,t) = \frac{1}{m(D)}\int_{x+D}T(\xi,t)\,d\xi$$
where $D$ is a nice region in the space containing $x$, and $x+D$ is a translation.

> **Question:** Does $\hat T_D$ satisfy $\nabla^2\hat T_D = \partial \hat T_D/\partial T$ ?

It seems physically reasonable to me that $\hat T_D$ should satisfy the same differential equation, and I know this is true in one dimension:

\begin{align}
\frac{\partial \hat T_D}{\partial t} 
&= \frac{1}{m(D)}\int_{x-a}^{x+b} \frac{\partial T}{\partial t}\!(\xi,t)\,d\xi \\
&= \frac{1}{m(D)}\int_{x-a}^{x+b} \frac{\partial^2 T}{\partial \xi^2}\!(\xi,t)\,d\xi \\
&= \frac{1}{m(D)}\left(\frac{\partial T}{\partial x}(x+b,t) - \frac{\partial T}{\partial x}\!(x-a,t) \right) \\
&= \frac{1}{m(D)}\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left[\int_0^{x+b}T(\xi,t) - \int_0^{x-a}T(\xi,t)\right]\right) \\
&= \frac{\partial^2 \hat T_D}{\partial x^2} 
\end{align}

The beginning of this argument extends well into higher dimensions by replacing FToC by Stokes:

$$m(D)\frac{\partial \hat T_D}{\partial t} 
= \int_D \nabla^2T(\xi,t)\,d\xi = \int_{\partial D} \nabla T(\xi,t)\,d\xi $$

However, to do the next part I used the fact that derivatives are linear to interchange the derivative and the difference; it's not clear if this is still possible in higher dimensions. Certainly the naive method of just pulling the nabla out of the integral does not work for simple dimensions considerations, but I'm not aware of a more sophisticated technique either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **Answer:** Yes it does, and there is a much simpler method using translational symmetry.

We begin as before, but then substitute $\zeta=\xi-x$ to remove the $x$-dependence of the boundary:

\begin{align}
\frac{\partial \hat T_D}{\partial t} 
&= \frac{1}{m(D)}\int_{x+D} \frac{\partial T}{\partial t}\!(\xi,t)\,d\xi \\
&= \frac{1}{m(D)}\int_{x+D} \nabla^2T(\xi,t)\,d\xi \\
&= \frac{1}{m(D)}\int_{D} \nabla^2T(\zeta+x,t)\,d\zeta,
\end{align}

Notice that the $\nabla^2$ described above differentiates with respect to $\xi=\zeta+x$. However, we can see from the chain rule that $f_{a+b}(a+b,\mathbf x)=f_b(a+b,\mathbf x)$ and therefore we can replace it with the $\nabla^2$ which differentiates with respect to $x$; this can then be removed from the integral:

\begin{align}
\frac{\partial \hat T_D}{\partial t} 
&= \frac{1}{m(D)}\int_{D} \nabla^2_xT(\zeta+x,t)\,d\zeta \\
&= \nabla^2_x\frac{1}{m(D)}\int_{D}T(\zeta+x,t)\,d\zeta \\
&= \frac{\partial^2 \hat T_D}{\partial x^2}.
\end{align}